# Merge two different data class lists in to the the third one Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to add additional field to my new data class from the old one which has an extra field of balance value. I have created data class list with the ID and the Values (balance), which I want to merge first data class list with the second to make 3rd list - similarly like union in sql.

**first data class**

```
data class Coin(
  val id: String,
  val price_usd: Double,
  val name: String,
  val rank: Int,
  val symbol: String
)
```

**second data class**

```
 data class CurrencyBalance(
     val id: String,
     val quantity: String
 )
```

The aim is to create this type of data class list

```
data class CoinData(
  val id: String,
  val price_usd: Double,
  val name: String,
  val rank: Int,
  val symbol: String,
  val quantity: String
)
```

Comment: your balance in `CurrencyBalance` is a String, but you expect `quantity` to be a double. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
fun convert(currencyBalances: List<CurrencyBalance>, coins: List<Coin>): List<CoinData> =
    currencyBalances.map { currencyBalance ->
        coins.firstOrNull { coin -> coin.id == currencyBalance.id }
            ?.let { coin -> CoinData(coin.id, coin.price_usd, coin.name, coin.rank, coin.symbol, currencyBalance.value) }
    }.filterNotNull()
```

I assumed here that the fields in a `CurrencyBalance` are called `id` and `value`

Comment: Thanks you, it worked. It takes 10 seconds to load data to the list maybe you have any idea how to optimize it 

Comment: there's probably ways to optimize it, but I'm not sure how. I don't know maybe if sorting both lists on id first, and then traversing them both would be faster than using `firstOrNull` every time

Comment: Another idea to optimise away the `firstOrNull` call is you could put all of the Coins into a hashmap first, keyed by their id. Then have a quick lookup inside the loop. Sorting both lists on id is a good idea too. I'm not sure which option would be faster, you might have to test with the actual dataset.

Comment: Also first using `map` and then `filterNotNull` is an unnecessary extra step which could be replaced with a single `mapNotNull`.

Comment: @RobCo good point, I wasn't aware of that function